# Object is being embedded in wrong parent mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm currently trying to load in a CSV to my MongoDB using MongoID. It works to an extent except the embedded documents are saved under the same root document floor.
Essentially there currently is an information document that contains info about a building. Under the information document I embed floors and within floors I can embed rooms. Similar to the structure below:

```
Information
   Floors
     Rooms 
       :name
       :thermostat_zone
```

My test CSV contains the following information:

```
floor   room    zone
1       101      A
1       102      A
1       102      B
1       104      C
1       105      D
1       106      E
1       107      F
1       108      G
4       109      G
2       201      H
2       202      I
2       204      J
2       207      J
2       209      K
2       208      L
2       210      M
3       214      N
3       215      O
3       216      P
3       225      Q
```

The only problem is that all of rooms currently embed under floor one, and I imagine there is something going on concerning object persistence eventhough whenever I take the time to print the floors out from the load in loop each floor is being printed out. I really hope someone can help me get beyond this problem! I come from a PHP/MYSQL background, so this is new to me.

```
@building_id = params[:building_id]
    owner = Owner.where('buildings._id' => Moped::BSON::ObjectId(@building_id)).first
    @building =  owner.buildings.find(@building_id)
    @building.information.floors.destroy


    CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true) do |row|
        floor_name = row['floor']
        room_name = row['room']
        zone_name = row['zone']
        floor = Floor.new
        floor = @building.information.floors.where('name' => floor_name).first
        if !floor || floor == nil
           floor = Floor.new
          floor.name = floor_name
          floor.information = @building.information
          floor.save
        end


        room = Room.new
        room.floor = floor
        room.name = room_name
        room.zone = zone_name
        room.save 
    end
```

Also, code for both Room.rb and Information.rb incase it is needed:

```
class Room
 include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :floor, :inverse_of => :rooms

  field :name
  field :zone
end
```

Information.rb: (narrowed down to just embedding stuff to make it easier)

```
#Building information
class Information
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :floors, :cascade_callbacks => true


end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this

```
if !floor || floor == nil
  floor = Floor.new
```

with

```
if !floor || floor == nil
  floor = @building.information.floors.create!()
  # OR
  floor = @building.information.floors.create!(name: 'name', zone: 'A')
```

same goes with rooms
replace this

```
room = Room.new
```

with this

```
room = floor.rooms.create!()
# OR
room = floor.rooms.create!(name: 'name', zone: 'B')
```

this is because that mongoid doesn't set the parent of embedded docs using `child.parrent_attr = parent` doesn't work properly...

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something similar to this that I didn't know.

Comment: did it work fine ?! or there is still other issues ?